Convert UIImage.size to String
if(image != nil){
    mediaSize = String(image!.size.width) + "|" + String(image!.size.height)
}

The result should be like "400|300"
I get the error: No exact matches in call to initializer
image is UIImage and I'm uploading it to the server before I try to convert the size to string and it's valid
Other questions about this aren't helping

Sorry, it's UIImage

The problem is that both height and width are CGFloat, which cannot be directly converted to a String using String.init.
You can either convert them to Double and then initialise a String from the Double
guard let image else { return }
let width = Double(image.size.width)
let height = Double(image.size.height)
mediaSize = String(width) + "|" + String(height)

Or simply use String interpolation, which does support CGFloat.
mediaSize = "\(image.size.width) | \(image.size.height)"

However, be aware that you're converting floating point numbers to a String, so you might end up with a non user friendly value with tons of decimal places. If you know that your values are integers, convert them to integers using Int(image.size.width) or format them to a fixed number of decimal places using either String(format:_:) or a NumberFormatter.

You can also use String(format:...):
var mediaSize: String = ""
let image = UIImage(named: "myImage")
if let image {
    mediaSize = String(format: "%0.0f|%0.0f", image.size.width, image.size.height)
    print(mediaSize)
}

The %0.0f means convert float to string, with NO decimals.
So your result would be "400|300"

Here’s a clean and reusable extension for converting an image size to a formatted string. This ensures your code is modular, readable, and easy to use across your project.
UIImage Extension
import UIKit

extension UIImage {
    /// Returns the image size as a formatted string: "width|height".
    func formattedSizeString(separator: String = "|") -> String {
        return "\(size.width)\(separator)\(size.height)"
    }
}

How to Use It
With this extension, you can directly call formattedSizeString() on any UIImage instance:
if let image = image {
    let mediaSize = image.formattedSizeString() // Default separator "|"
    print("Media size: \(mediaSize)")
}

// Using a custom separator
if let image = image {
    let mediaSize = image.formattedSizeString(separator: "x")
    print("Media size: \(mediaSize)") // Example: "1920x1080"
}

Key Features

Default Separator: The default separator is "|", but you can customize it when calling the method.
Code Reusability:

By encapsulating the logic in an extension, you avoid repeating string formatting logic throughout your code.
Readability:

Using a named method (formattedSizeString) makes it clear what the function does.



The answer does work, and with no problem, but what I don't understand in stackOverflow nowadays is people downvote without leaving the reason.
